# Inverse mapping theorem over a complete non-archimedean field

Tags: functional-analysis, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a complete field with respect to a non-trivial non-archimedean absolute value $|\cdot|$.
Let $E$ be a vector space over $K$.
A norm $||\cdot||$ on $E$ is a map $E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the following properties.

1) $||x|| = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$.

2) $||\alpha x|| = |\alpha|||x||$ for all $\alpha \in K$ and all $x \in E$.

3) $||x + y|| \le max(||x||, ||y||)$ for all $x, y \in E$.

Clearly $||x - y||$ defines a metric on $E$.
A vector space over $K$ equipped with a norm is called a normed vector space.
If $E$ is complete with respect to this metric, $E$ is called a Banach space.

Let $E, F$ be normed vector spaces over $K$.
Let $U$ be an open subset of $E$.
Let $a \in U$.
Let $f\colon U \rightarrow F$ be a map.
Suppose there exists a continuous linear map $L\colon E \rightarrow F$ such that
$$\frac {||f(x) - f(y) - L(x - y)||}{||x - y||} \rightarrow 0$$ when $(x, y) \rightarrow (a, a)$.
Then $f$ is called [strictly differentiable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_differentiability) at $a$.
It is easy to see that $L$ is uniquely determined by $f$ and $a$.
We denote $L$ by $Df(a)$.

The following proposition is stated without a proof in Bourbaki, Variete differentielles et analytiques.
How do we prove it?

**Proposition**
Let $E, F$ be Banach spaces over $K$.
Let $U$ be an open subset of $E$.
Let $a \in U$.
Let $f\colon U \rightarrow F$ be a map.
Suppose $f$ is strictly differentiable at $a$ and $Df(a)$ is an isomorphism $E \rightarrow F$.
Then there exist an open neighborhood $U_0$ of $a$ such that $U_0 \subset U$
and an open neighborhood $V_0$ of $f(a)$ with the following properties.

1) $f|U_0$ is a homeomorphism $U_0 \rightarrow V_0$.

2) Let $g$ be the inverse of $f|U_0$. Then $g$ is strictly differentiable at $f(a)$.

3) $Dg(f(a)) = Df(a)^{-1}$.

Comment: What have you tried? For example, how might a proof over the reals fail for the $p$-adics?

Comment: Actually, have you tried this book: http://books.google.ca/books?id=LzhkCF9ZsUgC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Andrew No. Does the book treat Banach spaces over a non-archimedean field?

Comment: It treats Banach spaces over $\Bbb R,$ but I thought that maybe the proof could be tweaked to work more generally.

Answer (score 1):

I've a quick reference for your question. Chapter 2 of [Igusa's book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=yPXK10jqMj8C&pg=PR6&lpg=PP1&dq=igusa&hl=es) on local zeta functions has proofs for the implicit function theorems over an arbitrary complete field. The non-archimedean case is treated in section 2.2. Good luck!!